# How do I recover a Gmail account?

Tags: email, gmail, account-recovery, google-account

I haven't used Gmail in a long time, but want to save it from deletion on June 1. I forgot my password for a bit, and tried to recover it thru Q&A, but, on starting with "Try Another Way," I was told I haven't provided enough info; I wasn't even asked for any. Under the impression that filling out the alternate email listed with the account was the start of it, I filled it out, and it sent a code to that email, resetting my password. That account went inactive some time ago. I subsequently recalled the formatting on my password. When I signed up, there was no mobile phone requirement.

So, how do I recover my account? Where's the Q&A talked about on the Help pages?